# insert data using cursor Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

Database: Oracle 11gr2;
Web application : JSP(Java)
I have two tables:

```
Cities(***Id***, Name); Id is the Primary Key
Persons(***IdPers***, Name, IdCity_FK); IdCity is Foreign Key
```

IdCity_FK reffers to column Id from Cities.

The question: how to insert data from a insert.jsp page which has the following fiels:Person's name, City.

I want the user to enter his name and to select a city from some ListBox dynamically generated (using Cursor Oracle or a other method).
 For instance, one does not enter : Andrew, 12, but enters Andrew and select New York. 
I managed to do this by using Oracle REF CURSOR, but when clicking submit I get error. I think it does not pass an int value as parameter.

The code

```
 create or replace 
FUNCTION GET_CITIES
RETURN CITYPKG.ref_cursor
AS cities_cursor CityPkg.ref_cursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN cities_cursor FOR
  SELECT id, nume FROM CITY;
  RETURN CITIES_cursor;
END;
```

In the JSP page for editing I have a jspforward tag which sends me to a page which handles the form with request.getParameter... and calls a function which has 2 parameters: one is String the other one is int. The int one inserts the corresponding foreign key in the database.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is too confusing.

Comment: If you use Numbers(INT values) as primary/foreign keys, how do you insert data in an application without knowing what  a value like 2 or 18 refers to. It's more natural to select a name of a city than to enter a foreign key value(from a user perspective).

Comment: Solved: There was an error at parameter inside JSP.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error at JSP file(parameter).